# 3D printing forum community

Tags: 3d-design

Is there any forum where expert designers can help beginners like me?

I am starting to design a panel for my car, and I am having some difficulties with finding a modeling program and using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See DesignSpark - [DS Mechanical](http://www.rs-online.com/designspark/electronics/eng/page/mechanical) is good, free and fun to use.